doubt in uniqueness of Hoffman linear algebra section 8.4 exercise 11

Let $V$ be an n-dimensional inner product space over the field $F$, and let $L(V, V)$ be the space of linear operators on $V$. Show that there is a unique inner product
on L(V, V) with the property that $||T_a,bl||^2 = ||a||^2\cdot ||b||^2$ for all $a, b\in V$.
$(T_a,b(r)=(r|b)a)$ Find an isomorphism between $L(V,V)$ with this inner product and the space of $n\times n$ matrices over $F$, with the inner product $(A|B) = tr (AB^*)$.


To prove uniqueness I think I should get $(T_a,b | T_r,d)$. To do this if I use the polarization identities then I should have $||T_a,b + T_r,d||$ but I don’t think there exist $s,t$ such that $T_a,b + T_r,d=T_s,t$. Can you help me?

Please use MathJax next time.
